# GC logs not showing up

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection

I am using java version :
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

on linux :
user1.local 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 14 20:46:41 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

with VM arguments :

```
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime 
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 
-XX:GCLogFileSize=600k 
-Xloggc:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/gc/today.log
```

I am not able to print the gc logs to today.log file. These flags work with java 1.8 jdk on a windows machine. I am not able to figure out what am I missing here.
appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: does this directory `/usr/local/tomcat/logs/gc` already exists?

Comment: thanks for the response. yes, this directory does exist. On windows machine, I used -Xloggc:C:\Users\myname\dir\testLogs\gclog.log. It wouldn't use gclog.log file but it created new file <gclog.log.0.current> and put the logs in this file.

Comment: Of course it does not use that provided single file name when you ask for log file rotation. How did you expect it to work if not by adding a number to the name?

Comment: that is a good point